# Change form action based on selection options?

Tags: jquery

I have a form as follows:

```
<form id="myformid" name="myformname" method="get" action="form1.php" onsubmit="return checkDependant()">
<fieldset>
<label>Food:</label>
<select name="Foods" size="1" class="search_input" id="selectid">
<option value="">Food Type</option>
<option value="Banana">Banana</option>
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
<option value="Pizza">Pizza</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" name="searchname" id="searchid" value="" />
</form>
```

The form should always be processed by form1.php except  if "Orange" is selected, then the form should be processed by form2.php. Can this be done using Javascript / JQuery?

Comment: What @Kerrek said, you really should go back and accept answers on your past questions.  People will start to ignore your questions if you never accept answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/EtbvE/

```
$("#myformid").submit(function(){
    if($("#selectid").val()==="Orange"){
        $(this).attr("action","form2.php");   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#selectid").bind('change',function(){
    var action =  ($(this).val()=="Orange") ? 'form2.php' : 'form1.php';
    $('#myformid').attr('action',action);        
});
```